# Flutter : Call a method inside listview builder from appbar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview builder with a list in the home page and when an item of the list is pressed a second page will open with details of that list. The details are basically another list of cards on each card I have a counter starts **with zero value**, when user press on each card the counter value will increase.

Now the issue I face is when user go back to home page and then again click on a the same item to go to the second page, they will find the counter values as there were (**i.e not zeros**), although I did not include any mechanism to store these values (i.e no sharedpreferance or so).

These values of the counter will not go back to zeros, unless the app is closed and open again.

I have tried to resolve this by adding a method on the second page, inside the listview.builder to change the counter value of each card to zero once the user go back to home screen. For this to work, I am calling the method from the appbar,  but I am getting this error ***"error: The method 'moveToLastScreen' isn't defined for the type '_DetailState'"*** . How to resolve this please

This is my code:

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              moveToLastScreen();
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.cities.attractions.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          void moveToLastScreen() {
            setState(() {
              widget.cities.attractions[index].localrank = 0;
            });
          }

          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                widget.cities.attractions[index].localrank++;
              });
            },
            child: Card(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(widget.cities.attractions[index].name),
                  Center(
                      child: Text(
                          '${widget.cities.attractions[index].localrank}')),
                ],
              ),
            )),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Please let me know is there is another way other than this, to force the app to reset these values to zeros as they were originally once the user go back to home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly you want to set all localranks in widget.cities.attractions to zero when the back button is pressed.

My first suggestions would be to use the WillPopScope widget to do what you want when back pressed instead of using the back button in the appbar, But more importantly you can't access moveToLastScreen method if it's defined there. You have to define it in the Widget class.
You can use forEach to access each attraction and set the localrank to zero from there.

```
  Future<bool> moveToLastScreen() async {
    setState(() {
       widget.cities.attractions.forEach((attraction) => attraction.localrank = 0);
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => moveToLastScreen(),
      child: Scaffold(...),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, it works as I want. Thanks Khashayar for the answer, appreciated.